# Images not rendering in ie8 which are provided through jquery and css

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

```
slider = {

    initializeWidget : function(parentNode, widgetModel)
    { 

  var slide = 

    '<style type="text/css">'+
   '.ui-slider {'+
    'position: relative;'+
    'text-align: right; '+
    'width: 575px;'+
    'margin:0px 0px 0px 0px'+
   '}'+
   '.ui-slider .ui-slider-innerBar{'+
    'height:16px;'+
    'width:575px;'+
     'margin:3px 0px 0px 0px;'+
    'background: url("desktopweb/images/slider_bg.png") no-repeat 0 0;'+
   '}'+
   '.ui-rangeSlider .ui-slider-handle{'+
    'z-index: 10;'+
    'width: 13px;'+
    'height: 20px;'+
    'border: 0px;'+
    'background: url("desktopweb/images/tooltip.png") no-repeat ;'+
   '}'+
   '.ui-slider .ui-slider-bar{'+
    'margin: 3px 0;'+
    'background: url("desktopweb/images/slider_bg_active.png") no-repeat 0 0;'+
    'background-position: left;'+
    'height:20px;'+
    'cursor:move;'+
    'cursor:grab;'+
    'cursor: -moz-grab;'+
   '}'+
   '.ui-slider-label{'+
    'margin:0 2px 2px;'+    
    'background: url("desktopweb/images/calendarbackground.png") no-repeat ;'+
    'background-repeat:no-repeat;'+
    'bottom:0px;'+
    'padding:6px 10px 15px;'+
    'cursor:col-resize;'+
   '}'+
  '</style>'+
  '<div id="slider1"></div>';
```

The images are rendered by hitting them using url of image.
Background images are not rendered on IE8, when the images url are given as above.
The custom widget is  written in JQuery 1.9.1.
Please help on this. 
Thanks in advance!!
PS: there are no errors shown, that images are not available in folder in console.

Comment: why use style css in jquery . please make it external css

Comment: Thanks dude, it worked. Is there any explanation for this thing?

Answer (score 0):

> An external stylesheet is a separate file with all your styles in it.
>   You link to it in the head section of your web page coding.